# NativeScript Playground QR code leads to default app

Tags: nativescript

I am using NativeScript Playground 5 with iOS 12.1

When I attempt to scan a QR code on Playground, the Preview application loads, but the project specified by the QR code does not load.

It was working a few scans ago, then suddenly this behavior crops up.

Things I have tried:

1. Re-installing the Playground and Preview App
2. Getting other phones to try the same QR code -- theirs work
3. Using my phone on other Playground projects -- doesn't work
4. Restarting my phone
5. Making sure that there's Internet access.

Comment: I had hit this issue a couple times in past (Android), clearing data of both apps solved it.

Comment: There don't seem to be an option for that in iOS. The two app don't show up in the storage section.

Comment: Is it reproducible with every project you try or with a specific one?

Comment: This is the only way now you can delete document and data in iphone. http://osxdaily.com/2016/08/08/delete-documents-data-iphone-ipad/

Comment: @DimitarTachev every project with the same phone leads to the problem.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling the NativeScript Preview app and install a fresh copy from the App Store?

Comment: In the end it's clearing the iOS cache data that does it. I was looking through the list for "NativeScript Playground" and missed it because the name of the app was just "Playground"

Comment: same issue here, none of the proposed workarounds make any difference.  Playground/Preview are completely useless on my iphone XR, works just fine on my cheap knock-off android phone for the same app though, go figure.